Application of Callias operator in physics
In his article "Axial Anomalies and Index Theorems on Open Spaces" C.Callias shows how the index of the Callias-type operator on $R^{n}$ can be used to study properties of  fermions in the field of $SU(2)$ Monopoles.
Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $D$ be the Dirac operator on $C_{c}^{\infty}(M,E)$ the section of the vector bundle $E$. Let $A \in End(E)$ a self-adjoint bundle morphism. We define a Callias-type operator by $D+iA$ such that it verifies the following

The commutator $[D,A]$ is an operator of order zero and uniformly bounded.

There exists a compact $K\subset M$ and a positive constant $c>0$ such that
$$A^{2}\geq c Id \quad \in M\smallsetminus K.$$


I would like to know how the Callias operator defined above can be used to count fermions in magnetic monopoles and what is the role of the pitential $A$.
